# Show Green's function solves Poisson's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am reading Walter Strauss's book Introduction to PDE. The definition of Green's function is as follows:
The Green's function $G(x)$ for the operator $-\Delta$ and the domain $D \subset \mathbb{R^3}$(here I assume $D$ is an open set and has a smooth boundary) at the point $x_0 \in D$ is a function defined for $x \in D$ such that:

(i) $G(x)$ possesses continuous second derivatives and $\Delta G=0$ in $D$,except at the point $x=x_0$.

(ii) $G(x)=0$ for $x\in \text{bdy} D$.

(iii) The function $G(x)+1/(4\pi|x-x_0|)$ is finite at $x_0$ and has continuous second derivatives everywhere and is harmonic at $x_0$.

My first question is:
How to show that such Green's function exists?

My second question is:
How to prove that the solution of the problem 
$$\Delta u=f \text{ in } D,u=0 \text{ on bdy }D$$
is given by 
$$u(x_0)=\int \int \int_D f(x)G(x,x_0)dx \text{ ?}$$

I know these questions can be explained in terms of distribution but since I haven't learnt distribution yet,I am looking for a more elementary solution.Thank you.

Comment: For (iii) did you mean "G(x)=" rather than "G(x)+"?

Comment: I mean there is a harmonic function H(x) on D such that H(x)=G(x)+1/(4\pi|x-x_0|) on D\{x_0}

Comment: Then should it be H in the integral?

Comment: The G(x) in the definition is for point x_0 so in fact G(x)=G(x,x_0).The function in the integral is G(x,x_0) not H.

Comment: $H$ is called a fundamental solution. You might want to take a look at Fritz John book. To prove it classically, you'll have to separate the singularity at $x_0$ from the rest of the integral (using a ball of radius $\epsilon$), and then investigate the behavior in the limit. I've used the argument [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/439260/19532)